# How do i automate testing of touch and multi-touch based web applications using selenium web driver?

Tags: testing, selenium, touch, multi-touch, ui-automation

I am writing some automated tests using cucumber and selenium for various web applications. Currently this is working well, however we are about to start making mobile specific versions of our pages.

I understand that a click is much the same as a touch, however there are some things we want to be able to test such as

- Dragging
- Swiping
- Rotating the device
- Pinch to zoom

I plan to implement most of this testing using selenium WebDriver and selenium grid, I have not had much experience with running any WebDrivers other than the Firefox WebDriver, however I couldn't find anything mentioning touch interfaces.  Is this something which is currently lacking from selenium, does anybody know of any other projects or drivers which might allow touch interface control?

With the explosion of mobile web devices and browsers, having an automated way of testing is the only way we can manage the testing of this.

Asserting the display of the page is another issue which is out of scope as far as this question is concerned, however I was planning on using a combination of selenium assertions and [fighting layout bugs](https://code.google.com/p/fighting-layout-bugs/) type testing

Answer (score 0):

How about this [blog](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2011/10/test-your-mobile-web-apps-with.html).

Example for rotating the device

```
 assertEquals(landscapeSize, secondImage.getSize()) 
((Rotatable) driver).rotate(ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT); 
assertEquals(portraitSize, secondImage.getSize());
```

Comment: This doesn't seam to cover pinching unfortunately :(